# 14.04 Laptop battery time increasing and decreasing

Tags: 14.04, battery

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my new laptop. Every thing is fine except the battery timing. When it is 100% fully charged the time starts from 16 hours and drops to 2 hours in just seconds then after that it again starts to increase from 2:30 to 2:45 from this to 3:00 and then to 3:30 and then again to 3:03 and it continues to change and sometimes it will start to decrease and then next moment it will start to increase. I am worried about it what should i do is it damaging my battery. Is there any solution to it?

```
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               Lenovo IdeaPad
serial:               BAT20101001
power supply:         yes
updated:              Sat 20 Dec 2014 12:08:07 PM PKT (26 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               discharging
energy:              22.92 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         29.1 Wh
energy-full-design:  31.68 Wh
energy-rate:         9.289 W
voltage:             14.84 V
time to empty:       2.5 hours
percentage:          80%
capacity:            89.9621%
History (charge):
1419059257  80.000  unknown
1419095897  68.000  charging
1419095834  0.000   unknown
1419067712  83.500  discharging
1419064634  79.000  charging
1419063171  0.000   unknown
History (rate):
1419059287  9.289   unknown
1419059242  9.234   discharging
1419095894  15.018  charging
1419095834  0.000   unknown
1419067616  10.567  discharging
1419065939  14.442  charging
1419065699  15.771  fully-charged
1419064392  14.716  charging
1419063171  0.000   unknown
```

**Update:**

```
   native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               Lenovo IdeaPad
serial:               BAT20101001
power supply:         yes
updated:              Thu 08 Jan 2015 10:08:07 PM PKT (5 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               discharging
energy:              18.59 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         26.42 Wh
energy-full-design:  31.68 Wh
energy-rate:         6.068 W
voltage:             14.84 V
time to empty:       3.1 hours
percentage:          70%
capacity:            83.3965%
```

Answer (score 0):

Laptop battery life can become unpredictable when it is on the verge of going completely bad.  Occasionally, and by that I mean one time out of ten, I can wake up a purportedly bad battery by repeatedly running down its 2-20 minute life span and putting it on charge until it thinks it is full, and after a few such cycles it wakes up and charges very long and then runs for ten hours or something incredible.

So just to be clear, it may not be a software issue, or even a laptop issue.  I'd hate to have you spend a lot of money on a new battery for you to find out, but you may need to.  If you give me the brand and model I'll see if I can find a good deal under $25.

Comment: ok should i install windows or continue using it ?

Comment: There is rarely, if ever, a good reason to install windows.  Let me put it this way, Do you intend to connect it to The Internet?

Comment: i installed Ubuntu because i want to build android kernel myself. Will this damage continue to grow ...

Comment: @user4687489, I take your question to mean, will the battery continue to get worse.  The answer is, "probably", but in actuality, using the method I described, it could get better.

Most laptop batteries use multiple parallels sets.  The laptop can run with only one set.  Most laptops use two sets.  Some laptops use three sets.  Each time a set fails, you lose that much capacity, so if you had two sets to begin with, the amount of capacity you would lose would be half.

Comment: can you please simplify your answer more..i cannot get it

Comment: I was explaining how MODERN laptop batteries (Li-Ion) lose capacity as it is quit different from nicad/nimh.

Comment: updated please help as it is affected more and more